# Getting nominative month name in date-fns

Tags: javascript, date-fns

How can I get the name of the month in nominative format?

```
import { format } from 'date-fns'; 
import { ru } from 'date-fns/locale';

format(new Date(), 'MMMM', { locale: ru }); // июня
```

How can I get the name like `юинь` instead of `июня`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I was able to find a solution. To get the stand-alone name of the month the `LLLL` format should be used.

The working code should look like this:

```
import { format } from 'date-fns'; 
import { ru } from 'date-fns/locale';

format(new Date(), 'LLLL', { locale: ru }); // июнь
```

See documentation -> Month (stand-alone): https://date-fns.org/v2.14.0/docs/format

Answer (score 15):

There are a few patterns you can use.

- LLL:   Jan, Feb, ..., Dec
- LLLL:  January, February, ..., December
- LLLLL: J, F, ..., D
- MMM:   Jan, Feb, ..., Dec
- MMMM:  January, February, ..., December
- MMMMM: J, F, ..., D

Comment: Any difference between LLL and MMM for example? Or are they just aliases for the same thing?

Comment: @AlbatrossCafe in the default locale (en-US) they are same, but in some locales they differ a little bit. In other languages LLL is stand-alone unit, MMM is not which means LLL returns the name of a month, when MMM is declined according to the rules of the language.

Answer (score 1):

Use the LLLL format to get full month names. I have tried and it worked!
example:

```js
import {format} from 'date-fns';
const formattedDate = format(new Date(), 'LLLL');
```

Comment: When answering questions on Stack Overflow, never put code examples in links, and especially never in image links. Use the Code Sample option in the text window to automatically format your code sample. [See how to format code manually](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Links are OK, but for images I mostly agree. Also @StephenMIrving feel free to improve his response yourself.